# In a React JS / Redux Table, if we add a record to the front of an array dynamically, and use the array index as the "key", why does it actually work?

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example, if we have an array

```
0 => San Francisco
1 => Taipei
2 => San Jose
```

and use the index as the "key" for every `<tr>` element like this

```
this.props.arrData.map((data, i) => {
    return (
        <tr key={i}>
        // ...
```

it should be fine. When we add to the end of array:

```
3 => Sacramento
```

And the index to data mapping is still all good -- just one more mapping is added.

However, I found that even if it is prepended to the array, and still use the index as the "key", it still work perfectly and don't know why.

I thought it should not work because at the very beginning with 1 record:

```
0 => San Francisco
```

and it will cache the key 0 as the HTML fragment of San Francisco.

And when a record is prepended:

```
0 => Taipei
1 => San Francisco
```

I thought React actually use the `0` as the key to this row, and somehow can "cache" this fragment, and so any `<tr>` with key=0, it would have it cached as San Francisco, so the table could become:

```
0 => San Francisco
1 => San Francisco
```

But it doesn't. So if something was cached, why would it actually work?

---

**P.S.** I ended up using:

```
var countTotalItems = this.props.weatherList.length;

return this.props.weatherList.map((weather, i) => {

  return (
    <tr key={`${countTotalItems - i} ${weather.cityName} ${weather.countryCode}`}>

  // ...
```

and the `key` is like: `1 San Francisco US` for the last row all the time, even when there are more items added to the array -- essential, just reverse the order by using a key of `1` at the end of array. I used the city and country as well to better identify the row, just in case, for example, if in the future a row can be deleted by the user.  But the question is, why if not reversing the order, it still works.

**P.P.S.** as I put in the comment of one answer: if the row is all text, I found no difference in using `key={cityName + i}` vs `key={i}`, but if the row contains an image using `<img />` of the weather condition, I do find a difference. If it is `key={i}` then the newest row will have the previous image for 1 to 2 seconds, and then the correct image will get in. But if it is `key={cityName + i}`, then the image will be blank, and then 1 to 2 seconds later, the image will get in. The latter behavior is more desirable... the former behavior can be a little confusing to the user.

Comment: I think this is related with "immutable" that I see in https://youtu.be/I7IdS-PbEgI. I don't think "cache" is the right word in this case, instead it give the components decision to re-render or not.

Comment: so if the key 0 element (or row) doesn't re-render, then it should stay as San Francisco...

Comment: I think it should.. I think, if you prepend data to array, it will rerender all the row, but if you append the data, only the last row that will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the point of the `key` when rendering repeated children.  They are used to optimise the rendering when items are added, removed or rearranged and not for "caching" their value.

In your example the rendered html would look something like:

```
<tr key='0'>Taipei</tr>
<tr key='1'>San Jose</tr>
```

If a "San Francisco" is added to the front of the array React will have to change every element to the new values and then add a new one at the end for because there isn't an existing element for "San Jose".  Now the html would look like:

```
<tr key='0'>San Francisco</tr>
<tr key='1'>Taipei</tr>
<tr key='2'>San Jose</tr>
```

Now, if we had used the city name instead of the index and ran through the same example, we would start with:

```
<tr key='Taipei'>Taipei</tr>
<tr key='San Jose'>San Jose</tr>
```

Now when the new item is added, React can use the keys to know that "Taipei" and "San Jose" haven't changed and the only changes it needs to make to the DOM is to add an element at the start for the "San Francisco" item. The resulting html would look like:

```
<tr key='San Francisco'>San Francisco</tr>
<tr key='Taipei'>Taipei</tr>
<tr key='San Jose'>San Jose</tr>
```

Ultimately, the text on the screen would be the same, but it happened it far fewer updates to the DOM.  IF your array had 10000 items in, you can see how much cheaper this approach would be.

Keys must be unique to the item within the list, so if you don't have something unique to use, then the index will have to do, but be aware of the performance implications.

For more details, take a read of the relevant sections of the React docs, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

Comment: so like you said, if it is for items "added", then when there were "Taipei" and "San Jose", there was key 0 and 1, and now "San Francisco is added, and won't the system think: ok, I have 0 and 1, and now 2 is added, so let me just add 2 to table... and it is 2 => San Jose... so it should become Taipei, San Jose, San Jose...  or are you suggesting React actually used the whole content of the row to index it... if so, then why use a `key={something}`?

Comment: I also have another concern... if this app is for checking the weather of the last 15 minute, it should be made so that the user can check Taipei at 1pm, and then check other cities, and then at 1:25pm (or even at 1:02pm), the user should be able to check it again and add the row regardless to the table (if it is just for the purpose of the user putting Taipei next to Hong Kong. If I use `key={cityName}`, then there won't be 2 rows of Taipei -- there will be only one... so it looks like I might use `key={i}` or `key={cityName + i}` and I wonder why `key={i}` just work as what I wanted

Comment: @太極者無極而生 React will render all the content each time into the virtual DOM.  It then uses that to make the [fewest adjustments to the actual DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary) as it can to make it so.  The `key` property is used to help it out when dealing with lists as the cascading effect of DOM changes can be avoided if the the identity of the element is known.  There is no advantage to using `key={cityName + i}` over `key={i}` as the key will change if the index changes, undoing any benefit.

Comment: if the row is all text, I found no difference in using `key={cityName + i}` vs `key={i}`, but if the row contains an image using `<img />` of the weather condition, I do find a difference. If it is `key={i}` then the newest row will have the previous image for 1 to 2 seconds, and then the correct image will get in. But if it is `key={cityName + i}`, then the image will be blank, and then 1 to 2 seconds later, the image will get in. The latter behavior is more desirable... the former behavior can a little confusing to the user

Comment: @太極者無極而生 interesting.  I guess the element the difference is that it the `key={i}` case, React is reusing the element and changing the `src` prop of the `img` tag, but using `key={cityName + i}` will be unique between changes and so it will remove the old element and insert a new one.

Comment: please see the P.S. and the P.P.S.