# Does React use the `key` as well as a hash value for the content of the list item or table row to decide whether needing a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example, if we have a table row:

```
<tr key={ticket.id}> ...  </tr>
```

I think the goal is so that this row doesn't need to be updated repeatedly if there is an addition of one or more rows to the table. React will just update the missing ones and let the existing ones with that `id` stay and not re-render them.

However, what if the data comes back, with that ticket changing in price?

For example, one of the tickets may come back, with the ticket id being the same, but the price has increased by $200.

So if React just use the id `345678`, and not re-render that row, then the user can see the old price. Only if the user refresh the whole page, then he or she can see the correct price.

Or does React actually hash the content inside that row, so that if the hashed value is different, re-render it anyway?  Possibly first by the key value, and check the hashed value. If it is the same hash value, do nothing; otherwise, re-render it anyway?

Comment: React already diffs the DOM and props are always kept fresh through rendering (unless you use `shouldComponentUpdate`). The main purpose of `key` is to ensure that React *doesn't* re-use something it shouldn't when things change. Imagine having 3 rows, and row 2 has some internal *state*, then you remove row 2. You then render 2 rows, and React doesn't know the 2nd row used to be the 3rd row unless you use `key`, and the internal state of the old 2nd row stays in place and now applies to what used to be the 3rd row (which is now the 2nd row). That's why you need `key`.

Comment: So if you use row index as id, that's not good? You could do that in React (and Angular)... so then is it just not as efficient but still works? Ultmately, the row's content should be correct no matter what key you use, but just how often the row is updated that's the difference. (Use record's id as key, better. Use row index as key, not as good but still works)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a React JS / Redux Table, if we add a record to the front of an array dynamically, and use the array index as the "key", why does it actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163538/in-a-react-js-redux-table-if-we-add-a-record-to-the-front-of-an-array-dynamic)

Comment: Yeah, using row index is not a good idea. Key should uniquely identify the row. You can generate a unique id to attach to your data if doesn't exist.